# How is the counting done in competitive jump rope?

Tags: officiating, video-review, jump-rope

In the sport of jump rope one of the disciplines is speed.

Videos of competitive jump rope can be found for example on the International Jump Rope Union official channel: https://www.youtube.com/@IJRU

I would like to understand how the counting is done. Is it done live by an official using a push button pushing at the same cadence as the athlete, mechanically using some sort of force plate in the ground, visually by recording the performance on video and counting, or some other system?

In several videos I've watched there seems to be an official in the back with some sort of click counter. Is this really how it's done? Then maybe video review to validate world records?